# In place rotation of overlay image on the background with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, overlay, rotation

I have a small (100x80) overlay image which will be placed at x=40, y=50 on a transparent background(800x600) and then rotated 80 degrees in place.

```
convert  -size 800x600 xc:none -background transparent m01.jpg -rotate 80 -geometry +40+50  -composite final.png
```

rotates the merged image. how can i rotate only the overlay image in place(over the background at +40+50)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out that the layer specific operations need to be grouped by ()

```
convert -size 800x600 xc:none -background transparent \
 \( -page +40+50 01.jpg -rotate 80 \) -flatten final.png
```

Comment: Hi! What if the first piece of this operation is an existing image instead of the transparent background? Do you know how to do it? I tried the same way you did, but the -page offsets both images and not only the overlay, as I want. Thanks!